# Customized sources.list for custom live CD

Tags: apt, live-cd, software-sources, chroot, uck

I recently built myself a custom live CD of Xubuntu 14.04.1. This live CD is used to distribute to my customers to install on their machines with a set of pre-installed applications, some of which are unofficial packages hosted on my company's server.

I use UCK (Ubuntu Customization Kit) and during creation in the chroot environment, I edited the sources.list file to connect to the host server of my company and successfully install the packages. Since they are signed, I also add the key with:

```
wget -O - <server_url>/keyFile | sudo apt-key add -
```

Now, so far so good. I can use the live CD to install on a fresh machine and everything is pre-installed as needed. The problem arises when trying to update these pre-installed applications. It turns out that the edited sources.list used in the chroot of UCK does not get installed, which kind of defeats the purpose of the live CD if the repository must be manually added every time the OS is installed.

Any suggestions how to accomplish a permanently edited sources.list using UCK?